# Monkey patching a Gem method in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, monkeypatching, friendly-id, overriding

I'm willing to use [friendly_id](https://github.com/btrepp/friendly_id) gem with Firebird, but I need to override a method that implements a specific SQL function with code related to Firebird.

I've created the file `config/initializers/friendly_id_monkey_patch.rb` containing the following code:

```
module FriendlyId
  class SlugGenerator
    def conflicts
      #my_code
    end
  end
end
```

However the application keeps executing the original gem's method, ignoring my patch. What could be wrong?